# C# EWS OAuth: AcquireTokenInteractive().ExecuteAsync() throws "ActiveX control cannot be instantiated because the current thread isn't single-threaded

Tags: c#, multithreading, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement the delegate authentication route described by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

However, the code sample they provide throws this exception:

> 'ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be
> instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded
> apartment.'

I copy & pasted the code sample into a new, empty ASP.NET RESTful API project using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Afterward, I installed the latest version of Microsoft.Identity.Client and, as required by the call to`.ExecuteAsync()`, made the containing method async. The result is this code:

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult>  Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            var appId = "8e0523b2-c9a6-4b6f-971a-02bcd0eebf1d";
            var tenantId = "8ffb3be7-83a7-463f-a543-aedb2683b1ae";

            var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
            {
                ClientId = appId,
                TenantId = tenantId
            };

            var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

            // The permission scope required for EWS access
            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };

            try
            {
                // Make the interactive token request
                var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

                // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
                var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
                ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);

                // Make an EWS call
                var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(10));
                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Folder: {folder.DisplayName}");
                }
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
            }

            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The fix for this error is supposed to be as simple as giving the method the `STAThread` tag, or constructing your own thread and executing the method inside of it.
However, the method that throws the exception is an Async method! It requires multi-threading!? So I have to make the containing method async and can't construct my own thread to execute the code because I can't find a way to pass an async method call to the constructor for `new Thread()`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Am I right in thinking it's an impossible problem trying to run an Async method inside an STAThread?
Are there any other ways to retrieve the token for a current user?